# prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z} / 36\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Could I have a good explanation about why the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$ are $2\ \mathbb{Z}$ and $3\ \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: could you write a good explanation of what you have tried...

Comment: Remember the Lattice Isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Hint: prime factos

Comment: Well, by the Lattice Isomorphism theorem, I know there is a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$ and its ideals which are of the form $n \mathbb{Z}$, where $n|36$. From there I have trouble proving how to find the prime ideals. I know it has to do with the correspondence theorem (lattice isomorphism) again, but I can't give a more thorough explanation. To tell you the truth, I'm not completely comfortable with the correspondence theorem.

Comment: @MartinaK. Well, the key thing to note that the prime ideals $\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$ are precisely those lying above $(36)$. What primes lie above $(36)$?

Comment: @MartinaK. You mean $2\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$ and $3\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Well, $2\mathbb{Z}$, $3\mathbb{Z}$, $4\mathbb{Z}$, and $6\mathbb{Z}$. I know $4\mathbb{Z}$ and $6\mathbb{Z}$ are not prime ideals, but I know this for a stupid reason...because $4$ and $6$ are not prime.

Comment: @Chandrasekhar You're right.

Comment: Let us try a less complicated problem... Do you know what are all the ideals in $\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$??? Do you see somehow that : for an ideal $I\subseteq R$, Any ideal of $R/I$ is of the form $J/I$ where $J$ is an ideal of $R$ and $I\subseteq J$???

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik The second question does not make sense to me, so no, I don't see that.

Comment: Ok, let's not complicate it... let us go with first question.. do you see what are all ideals in $\mathbb{Z}/ 36\mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: @MartinaK. Well, you can use the following result: If $R$ is a commutative ring with unity then $P$ is a prime ideal in $R$ $\iff$ $R/P$ is an integral domain. Clearly $\frac{\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and so it should work. Similarly it should work for $3\mathbb{Z}$ as well. For other case it can't work

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes, all the ideals are of the form $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ where $n|36$, as I mentioned earlier

Comment: @Chandrasekhar Ok, I see.

Comment: @MartinaK.: do you see why is it so??? do you want to assume it for time being??

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I'll tell you the truth, I don't intuitively understand why. I would like to, though, instead of to just assume it as I have been doing.

Comment: Ok, let us digress from that for a while... all you know is $n\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$ are all ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$... Now, (assuming $(R/I)/(J/I)\cong R/J$) do you see what is $\frac{\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}}$ isomorphic to??? and then use that $I$ is prime ideal iff $R/I$ is integral domain....

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes, it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$, which is isomorphic to $n \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: do you see for what values of $n$ (extra conditions) $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain??

Comment: Only when $n$ is prime.

Comment: I have mentioned that you need some "extra conditions"... $n$ is prime, $n< 36$ and $n$ divides $36$.. do you now see what are all that $n$??

Comment: Ok, I see how to finish this. I get it! I appreciate you taking me through this.

Comment: It is not done yet.. It would be more clear if you can write all this (with details wherever possible) as an answer for your question so that this will not be left as unanswered...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The descriptions of ideals in quotients tells you that the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $k\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$, where $k$ divides $36$.

Now an ideal $I$ of $R$ is prime iff the quotient ring $R/I$ is an integral domain, and by the third isomorphism theorem you have :

$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}}{k\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}}\simeq \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$$

of course $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain iff k is prime (check) thus $k$ is a prime dividing $36$, i.e. $2$ or $3$.